# Redirect to user on specific area after login based on there role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, user-roles

i am creating web application using  dot net core 6.0. application contain two type of user one is admin and second is simple user area. i want that when user is login base on there role he/she redirect to there area like if user is admin he redirect to admin area. else redirect to user area.
`

```
@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
 {
 if (User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
 {
 Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "AdminDashboard", new { Area = "SuperAdmin" }));
}
else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
{
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "User", new { Area = "User" }));
}
}
```

`
i try this code in layout file but this code in not work properly

Comment: How does it no work? Can you provide more details? Also, please indent your code properly, it makes it much more easier to read and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

try this methods

```
@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
var user =await    userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);
var roles = await  userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
if (roles.Contains("SuperAdmin"))
 {
 Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "AdminDashboard", new { Area = 
 "SuperAdmin" }));
 }
}
```

I think this can help you!